# response undefined; cant work out where to define it

Tags: reactjs

trying to fetch a link, with .then(response, but keeps saying response is undefined? 
been stuck on this for ages aand just cant work it out

thanks

ps heres the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          .then(repsonse => return response.json())
          .then(users => this.setState({robots: users}));

 }
```

Comment: Typo: `repsonse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple typo there in the argument of the arrow function. You wrote **repsonse** instead of response, so in the function, it couldn't find response, and only has access to repsonse.

Comment: cannot believe i missed that! maybe just needed a second pair of eyes! thanks!